# Combine columns where there is only one data cell per row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google Sheets data that looks like this:

```
    A | B | C 
   -----------
1 | a |   |  
2 |   | b | 
3 | c |   |
4 |   |   | d
5 |   | e | 
6 | f |   | 
7 |   |   | g
8 |   | h |
```

I need to combine this data into one column like this:

```
| D |
-----
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  g
  h
```

For every row, there is only one data cell in Columns A, B, or C. Is it possible to do this using a Google Sheets formula?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: `=A1&B1&C1`, just copy down as many rows as you want; if you want to convert to values, use Copy/Paste Special>Paste values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type : **strings**

use some concatenation. Try this in `D1`

```
=ArrayFormula(A:A&B:B&C:C)
```

---

Data type : **value**

> If you have number data then include a `VALUE()` function like so:
>     `=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(A:A & B:B & C:C))`
>   **Credit to @iandllnghm in the comments of this answer.**

Comment: This works perfect as is for string data. Thank you for the suggestion. For others' reference, if you have number data then include a `VALUE()` function like so: `ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(A:A & B:B & C:C))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the OFFSET function in the following formulas:

```
+----+----+---+---+-----------------+
|  A |  A | B | C |       D         |
+----+----+---+---+-----------------+
|  1 | a  |   |   | =A1             |
|  2 |    | b |   | =OFFSET($A2,,1) |
|  3 |    |   | c | =A3             |
|  4 |    | d |   | =OFFSET($A4,,2) |
|  5 | e  |   |   | =OFFSET($A5,,1) |
|  6 |    | f |   |                 |
|  7 |    |   | g |                 |
|  8 |    | h |   |                 |
|  9 | i  |   |   |                 |
+----+----+---+---+-----------------+
```

We place them in the `D` column starting from cell `D1`
Since we have a repeating pattern we **select and drag down cells `D3-D5`.**

Comment: There is not a repeating pattern to the data. Thank you, though.

Comment: _"not a repeating pattern"_. It looked like it. In any case the answer by pjmg is more general and a better fit for you. Glad it worked out.